# What are these three references from episode 9?

Tags: watamote

In episode 9, there are these three references I didn't get:

- The first one is around minute 5, when Tomoko goes to see Yuu-chan at her uncle's café. She sees the names of two cakes ("Tarte Chiboust au Caramel" and "Bijou des Rois"), and then says this:

  [image: "It's so different from Fuya or Co **ner"]
- The second is around minute 15, when Tomoko is cleaning her stuff up. She wonders why her brother is trying to be better than her at everything, then says the following:

  [image: "Who is he, Kenshi***?"]

  She then says "I'm gonna make him cry for this."
- The third one is around minute 17, when Tomoko is cleaning her stuff up and finds the cicada shells. She remembers why they were there, says "A memory best left forgotten", and then:

  [image: "Only Shoko**n would want these anyway."]

What do these three different situations refer to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Fujiya](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%8C%E5%AE%B6) (不二家) and [Ginza Cozy Corner](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%8A%80%E5%BA%A7%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC) (銀座コージーコーナー), Japanese pastry/cake shop franchises
2. [Kenshiro](http://hokuto.wikia.com/wiki/Kenshiro), from *Fist of the North Star*, for the Big Dipper
3. Shoko-tan, for her [cicada-based](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2012/08/13-1/shokotan-revives-cicada-skin-fashion) fashion